# How to pass namespace in function in another file?

Tags: php, function, namespaces, microsoft-graph-api, global

Here is my code and what I'm running into:

```
// index.php

require "/var/www/functions.php";
use Microsoft\Graph\Graph;
use Microsoft\Graph\Model;
$microsoftGraph = new Graph();

test();



// functions.php

function test($microsoftGraph) {
    $create = $microsoftGraph->createRequest('POST', $create)
    ->setReturnType(Model\Event::class) // This is where I'm having a problem
    ->execute();
}
```

The error is saying:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Event' not found in...

---

**BUT...** if I put the `use` in my functions.php like this, it works:

```
use Microsoft\Graph\Graph;
use Microsoft\Graph\Model;

function test($microsoftGraph) {
    $create = $microsoftGraph->createRequest('POST', $create)
    ->setReturnType(Model\Event::class) // This is where I'm having a problem
    ->execute();
}
```

but how can i "pass" or NOT put `use` in the `functions.php` file?

Comment: Dare I say this out loud? Then leave the `use` statements there, that I believe is what they are there for

Comment: @PatrickQ Thank you for the link. Tried Googling every possible thing I cud think of but nothing.